# Excluding Columns of a pandas dataframe based on row mean values

Tags: pandas, subset, mean

I have a pandas dataframe, df 
and have calculated the row mean values:

```
df['means']=df.mean(axis=1)

   means            col1          col2     col3
    2                3              1       2
    2                2              1       3
    1                1              1       1
    1                0              1       2
    2                0              1       5
```

What I need is a way to exclude all columns within which all values are below or equal to the row average. For example, in col2 above, all values are either below or equal to the mean values and therefore should be excluded. Thus the output should be:

```
means           col1     col3
2                3          2
2                2          3
2                1          1
2                1          2
2                0          5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `all` with `le`

```
# notice I did not assign the new column means here. 
df.loc[:,~df.le(df.mean(1),0).all()]
Out[27]: 
   col1  col3
0     3     2
1     2     3
2     1     1
3     0     2
4     0     5
```

Comment: Looks perfect (-:

Comment: Could you explain? looks pretty nifty.